# The difference between get_id and GetCurrentThreadId

Tags: c++, windows, boost-thread

I want to get the thread id through `boost::thread:::get_id` and `GetCurrentThreadId`. 
       but but the results are different.
       I use boost::thread to do multi-threading. Why does the same thread have two different ids using get_id and GetCurrentThreadId?

```
  boost::thread* dl_thread = m_thread_group.create_thread(boost::bind(download,url,dest));
  *threadId = *reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(&dl_thread->get_id());
  DWORD threadIdsss = GetCurrentThreadId();
```

Comment: Well in your code dl_thread is different than the ThreadId(). Since you are starting everything from one main thread (I'm assuming here) so GetCurrentThreadId() returns the Id of the main thread, whereas *threadId holds the id of the already-started thread.

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of problems with your code, and with your question.

1. `GetCurrentThreadId` returns the Windows thread id of the thread calling the function. In your example, dl_thread isn't the thread calling the function.
2. `boost::thread::id` is an abstraction and may or may not correspond directly to an OS specific notion of thread id. It is not safe to assume that `boost::thread::id` can be used interchangeably with a `DWORD`. The casting shenanigans you had to go through to compare the two should have given you a hint that this was the case.

Finally, to answer your question: the same thread *doesn't* have a different id, even if you used `boost::this_thread::get_id` and compared that to `dl_thread.get_id` they would be different, because they *are* different threads.

Answer (score 0):

You have two threads there. And the second - created by boost, is not even running...

Boost thread do not know anything about the application thread in which has been run from. There is even no method how you could "assign" this thread to any instance of boost:thread.  Method boost::thread:::get_id returns class id of threads which are managed by boost:thread only, not by system. And the thread in which you perform GetCurrentThreadId call, is managed (probably) by system...